# How to create a button from an image with no click animation?

Tags: html, button

I have an image that I'm required to use for a button, and currently the button is just an `<a>` tag with an image and a click event. When clicked, it doesn't do the little depress animation that makes it look like it sinks into the page.

How can I replicate this behavior using an actual `<input>`?

Comment: Borders and outlines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/150/150" width="150" height="150" />
</button>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TLR67/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with input tag give it a class than use css to add the image

```
.inputImage
{ 
    background-image:url('yourpic.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;  padding-left:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try CSS and HTML and JQuery to create the button so it can be used multiple times.

JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/c7eDD/**

HTML:

```
<a class = "button">A</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.button {
    background:      #ffffff;
    padding:         2px 8px 2px 8px;      /* Button padding */
    font-size:       12px;
    font-weight:     bold;
    display:         inline;
    color:           #888888;
    border:          1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:   32px;                 /* Rounder corners */
    font-family:     Arial, sans-serif;

    cursor:          pointer;          /* Resurrect the pointer */
    text-decoration: none;                 /* Remove default underline style from hyperlink */
}

/* I decided to separate gradients */
a.button {
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.Hover {
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb !important;
    color: #777777 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #dddddd;
}

.Pressed {
    background: rgb(229,229,229) !important;
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 1px 0px #cccccc inset;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #cccccc inset;
   box-shadow:         0px 1px 1px 0px #cccccc inset;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(".button").mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("Hover");
    });

    $(".button").mouseout(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("Hover").removeClass("Pressed");

    });

    $(".button").mousedown(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("Pressed");
    });

    $(".button").mouseup(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("Pressed");
    });

});
```

Comment: You can use `background: url();' to set the image.

Comment: No problem. As long as you accomplished what you are looking for. :)